# Apple Mac mini install Win XP and 7 on?

Tags: windows-7, boot, mac, windows-xp, boot-camp

I have a 2010 Apple Mac mini Server (Unibody) here that I’d like to be able to boot into both Microsoft Windows XP and 7, in addition to macOS, for the purposes of running some old automotive programs from the late 90’s and early 2000’s.

It has dual hard drives (upgraded to SSD) which currently only has a fresh installation of macOS 10.13 High Sierra on one which will facilitate a Windows 7 Boot Camp installation through the macOS Boot Camp app.

I have ISO files of the Windows installers and valid product keys that were purchased.
I’ve got a USB Apple SuperDrive and a number of USB drives.

Any guidance please on how best to make this a triple OS machine? Please and thank you.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Does the Windows XP ISO have SP2 included? Are both XP and 7 the 32 versions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot likely boot XP on this machine - XP is most likely too old at this point. It depends on the host machine characteristics.

Triple Boot will likely cause all kinds of issues. Changes to the Mac system may cause issues.

The practical way to do this is with VMware Fusion (possibly Parallels). VMware is very flexible and I use Workstation on Windows.

Once installed, you can load XP and Windows 7 and any other operating systems you have.  Whether you can still update the old systems is another matter, but they should run.

Comment: Can you please explain the XP is too old part? I ask as XP (32 bit) was the Boot Camp option when this 2010 Mac mini was released with its original OS, Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard which included Boot Camp 3 app.

Comment: XP is too old because, so far as I know, there is no way to update it.  Triple boot can also be problematic. You can try, but if you mess up, you may need to reinstall the Mac OS .